# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client error nodejs error

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I am trying to post login data in Postman I get an error Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client.

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
const User = require('../models/user');
const Crypto = require('crypto-js');
const { response } = require('express');
const secretKey = process.env.SECRET_KEY;
//  Create a registration

router.post('/rejestracja', async (req, res)=>{
    const nowyUser = new User({
        email: req.body.email,
        password: Crypto.AES.encrypt(req.body.password, process.env.SEC_KEY).toString(),
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        surname: req.body.surname,
        username: req.body.username,
    });
    try{
        const newedUser = await nowyUser.save();
        res.status(201).json(newedUser);
    }
    catch(err){res.status(500).json(err)};
})
 
// Create a login

router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});
        !user && res.status(401).json("i/lub hasło jest nieprawidłowy");
        

        const securedPass = Crypto.AES.decrypt( user.password, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
        const password = securedPass.toString(Crypto.enc.Utf8);
        
        password !== req.body.password && res.status(401).json("Email i/lub hasło jest nieprawidłowy");
        
        response.status(200).json(user);
        console.log("dziala");
    } 
    catch(err) {
        res.status(500).json({message: err.message});
    }
    
});


module.exports = router
```

[Error Scr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLpQF.png)

I've tried to put process.env.SEC_KEY in this file but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're trying to send response twice:

```
password !== req.body.password && res.status(401).json("Email i/lub hasło jest nieprawidłowy");
    
response.status(200).json(user);
```

Also you're using `response` imported form the express. I'm not sure why you need it, but you probably should use the existing `res` instead.

All in all, I believe that the solution you're looking for is this:

```
if (password !== req.body.password) {
  res.status(401).json("Email i/lub hasło jest nieprawidłowy");
} else {
  res.status(200).json(user);
}
```

Good luck :)

Comment: now I get this in Postman "message": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'words')"

Comment: then you need to find out, where do you try to get property `words` and ensure that the object you're trying to read that property from exists

Comment: @Z3eme - since this fixed your issue, make sure to mark it as the accepted answer so that stolen_orange gets the credit and the question can be marked as closed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to break out of your code flow whenever you perform a `res.status(x)`. In cases such as this:

```
!user && res.status(401).json("i/lub hasło jest nieprawidłowy");
```

You'll set the status and the JSON of the response, but the code will continue, so you'll eventually get to setting the status again (either to 401 if the password isn't there, or 200 if it is).

Try something like this instead:

```
if (!user) {
  return res.status(401).json("i/lub hasło jest nieprawidłowy");
}
```

(Same thing for the password check.)